# Decodable: Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Tags: swift, codable, decodable

I've been staring at this for a while and I can't seem to figure out how to help the compiler. I'd like to make the functions generic so they can be reusable.

I removed everything inside the functions and where `makeServiceCall` gets called but I still see the error:

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

```
public func sendURLRequest<T: Decodable>(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {

}

public func makeServiceCall<T: Decodable>(url: URL, _ completion: @escaping (T)-> Void ) {
    sendURLRequest(url: url){ response in
    }
}
```

If I add `T` to sendURLRequest `sendURLRequest<T>(url: url)` I see the warning:

> Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function

. `sendURLRequest<T: Decodable>` returns another error:

> Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type '(URL,
>   @escaping (Result<_, Error>) -> Void) -> ()' and 'T.Type'

Thanks for any help! I'm on iOS 13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler can't infer the type in this case, so you need to specify it explicitly:

```
public func makeServiceCall<T: Decodable>(url: URL, _ completion: @escaping (T)-> Void ) {
    sendURLRequest(url: url) { (response: Result<T, Error>) in
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm you are you saying there’s no way to make it generic? Why would that be?

Comment: In Xcode 11.5, the error message is `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred` - I think that better describes it, and that's why the type has to be specified explicitly.

Comment: I misread what you wrote, I didn't realize you added `(response: Result<T, Error>)` - thanks!